# Unable to set routes on elixir phoenix umbrella project

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm creating an umbrella project using Phoenix 1.3. Structure is something like this:

- MainDirUmbrella

  - apps

    - my_app

Expecting to target the path *localhost:4000/rates/:coin*, I set the following route in router.ex:

```
scope "/rates", MyAppWeb do
  get "/:coin", RatesController, :show
end
```

For which `mix phx.routes` returns:

```
rates_path  GET  /rates/:coin  MyAppWeb.RatesController :show
```

But when I try to access a route like *localhost:4000/rates/usd* I get a Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError: "not route found.."

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server? Sometimes it fails to recompile your changes automatically

Comment: how do you start your app? Looks like your app is not initialized.

Comment: i use docker @ash. The home route of the app displays fine (the standard phoenix Wellcome page), so apparently it is initialized.